# Strange behavior for missing files with short URLs

Tags: apache, url, http-status-code-404

My webserver shows an error for missing pages. These URLs all 404:

```
http://my.web.site/missing.html
http://my.web.site/missing/
http://my.web.site/missing
```

But these URLs redirect to `/` with a `301 Moved Permanently`status code:

```
http://my.web.site/m/
http://my.web.site/m
```

Why do these URLs not 404? And how can I turn the 301 redirection off?

Since I don't have access to http.conf on this shared server (Apache), I am looking for a solution in .htaccess.

Just to clarify: What I want is that all missing pages 404.

---

Note:

The observed behavior (301 for one letter URLs) is the default on my (shared) webspace. **There is *no* .htaccess file** at this moment. I'm looking to resolve this issue *with* a .htaccess file.

Comment: Can you post the .htaccess file ? It's probably due to some bad rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks, @Piry, that would be a good udea but there is no .htaccess file. My question was misleading about that and I edited it. Sorry for that.

Comment: There should be `.htaccess` file. Check this. [How you can locate your .htaccess file.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937009/htaccess-where-is-located-when-not-in-www-base-dir). Once you locate, update a question with your RewriteRules.

Comment: Or, you could ADD a .htaccess file, so it is used instead of the default one from your shared hosting.
Anything simple should be fine.

Comment: There is no .htaccess. Trust me.

Comment: Who is hosting the site? It may be that they control the `.htaccess` file from the control panel of that host.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen Did you read my previous comment? How can anyone control a file that does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior described in my question is caused by the Apache module [`mod_spelling`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html). Creating a `.htaccess` with

> CheckSpelling Off

solved the problem.

---

I am disappointed that my bounty was awarded to an "answer" that (a) did not answer my question, (b) suggested a "solution" that would cause the exact behavior I was trying to avoid (301), and (c) my comment that points this out was ignored by the answerer.

Answer (score 1):

as you know you don't have access of http.conf file so first you need to check that your htaccess rewrite is working or not

If it is working (for checking it you can write some environment variable

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev_dev
```

and check in `$_SERVER`

Now time to do something in htaccess for 301 redirection

I have write this code in my HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^testurl/?$ /home/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

I don't know you want to redirect from which URL to which , But
in my code xyz.com/testurl will redirect to xyz.com/home

here my application is codeIgniter so might be you have page extension .php or .html like this

Comment: .htaccess and mod_rewrite are workung. I have them for other domains. I want the missing page to 404. I do *not* want to redirect it. Your solution is the current behavior.

Comment: I don't have an Apache system to test on, but I tried http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ with http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/ and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html for these:  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[a-z]{1}$ http://example.com/$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[a-zA-Z]/$ http://example.com/no_page.html [L]
they might not work (and I don't know what would cause the problem except a regex fixing short URL's that don't end with .html)

Comment: **This "answer" suggests as a solution the exact behavior I want to avoid. Why anyone would upvote an "answer" that suggests the problem as a solution to the problem is beyond me.** I am deeply disappointed that @ChintanGor ignored my comment pointing this out and that others upvoted this non-answer, causing my bounty to be awared to it.